# Need help figuring out a daisy chain issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

We have a goofy process (don't we all?) that daisy chains (or cascades) on a table that needs flattening out for our data warehouse.

The field "alt_key" is an identifier field. It ends up being the parent to other alt_key and alt_key2 data.

What I have below is an example of how the data looks. This table is named MEMBER

The record where alt_key = 05526396 is our "master" record, and the other records daisy chain down alternating between the alt_key and alt_key2 fields as shown in the picture below:

[![Record Daisy Chain][1]][1]

In the end, the records need to look like this. alt_key will be named primary_pmi and alt_key2 will be named pmi. if the row is a parent,  alt_key and alt_key2 will be the same as will the primary_member_nbr and member_nbr fields. **pmichain_id and pmi_order can be ignored**:

[![Final Daisy Chain Transformation][2]][2]

Not sure how I can get to the end dataset. I've tried a recursive CTE but I think I have too many records to process. How else can I go about this? Records can have many children

Comment: That data does not match

Comment: I've updated my question. The primary_pmi field and the pmi field will have the same data at the end, as will the primary_member_nbr and the member_nbr.

Comment: In this example , How do you know that `image_recnbr=748869` is the head of your chain and/or that `05526396` is the `primary_pmi`?  Is it because `05526396`  never appears in any `alt_key2` field?

Comment: You should know that this is the kind of thing that is much better handled by client coding languages than by SQL on the database.  it can be done by SQL, but the code is usually not good SQL and the performance is usually less than great.

Comment: Where do those numbers come from?  Those numbers are not in first table.

Comment: RBarryYoung, that is correct. It will never appear in any alt_key2 field.

Comment: paparazzo, if you're talking about pmichain_id and pmi_order, they can be ignored. One is an auto incrementing key and the other I will generate

Comment: Um - while we generally prefer to include actual text data in questions over images of data (it's easier to work with, to better understand the problem), removing the pictures without replacing them with text doesn't do much to make your question clearer....

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to approach this would be to use a loop.

Start by identifying your records where alt_key does not show up in any alt_key2 values. Load those into a staging table with pmi_order 1, and mark the records as processed in the source table (add a bit field to track this). These are your parent records.

Now start your loop with an index (n) of 2, and keep going up by one for each loop. For each staging record with pmi_order = (n-1), find the unprocessed main table record whose alt_key value matches the staging alt_key2 value. This becomes your pmi_order 2 (i.e. current value of n) record for that primary_member_nbr. (Note, you will alternate matching staging.alt_key2 to main.alt_key and staging.alt_key to main.alt_key2 for each execution of the loop.)

After each loop completes, check to see if any unprocessed records remain in the main table. Once you have exhausted the main table, you are done.

Comment: This works, but neither the performance, nor the code is great.  This is also pretty close to how a recursive CTE query does it's processing, so that could be done as well.  The code would be (slightly) better, performance would probably be about the same as the best looping code.  There's no reasonable set-based code for this that I know of.

Comment: CTE was my first attempt, but since there are 12,000 records this needs to process, it ends up choking. Not sure if I'm writing incorrect code

Comment: @RBarryYoung Agreed, it's not elegant, but it seems a recursive approach isn't working for the OP. To me this was a simple way to batch each level of the recursion without overwhelming the system by trying to stuff it all into a single transaction. And I also agree with your comment in the main question, but a client-side solution is out of the scope of dba.stackexchange - the OP might find better options cross-posting this to stackexchange.